# Eigenvalues of a specific problem: the product of matrix and its hermitian

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I don't think I could elaborate any longer in the title, sorry for that.

I have a very specific problem, I am trying to find the eigenvalues of a product of matrices that follow a certain set of properties. I have one matrix:

$$S = s C + C^Ts\,,$$

where $s$ is a symmetric matrix (let's say it is diagonal with positive entries), $C$ is an idempotent matrix ($C^2 = C$), and it is also hermitian. $C$ and $s$ also follow: $CsC^T = C^Ts C = 0$.

All of the matrices are square of dimension $n$.

I am trying to find the eigenvalues of $S S^\dagger$, is there a nice way of obtaining them? I am not necessarily looking for the answer (but if someone can derive one, it would be nice), but mostly looking for guidance on how could I begin.

I do know the shape that both $C$ and $s$ have, and I have been calculating the eigenvalues using Mathematica for $n=2$, the simplest case, and I arrived to a nice answer, but when I tried for $n=3$, Mathematica could not arrive to a nice answer.

Comment: Perhaps another property that may or may not be important. The reason why $C$ is idempotent is because $C = U^\dagger U$, where $U$ is a non-square semi-unitary matrix (meaning $U U^\dagger = I$). I do not know if this would be of any use.

Comment: You may want to start with the (relatively) simple case where $C$ is real. Even in that case, the relationship between the properties of $s$ and those of $S$ is complicated; you're ultimately asking for the relationship between a matrix and its [compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_(functional_analysis)). I think that the best you can hope for are bounds on (i.e. inequalities regarding) the eigenvalues of $SS^\dagger$ in terms of the properties of $s$ and $C$.

Comment: Incidentally, the property you mention in your comment holds for every idempotent and Hermitian matrix $C$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann thanks for your comments. I manage to not properly arrive to the solution, but I arrived to something which has left me satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to solve the problem in a way that left me satisfied for now. I doubt a lot of people would find the solution to this specific problem useful in any way, but I'll share my answer regardless. Even though I did not manage to find the eigenvalues, I managed to (block)-diagonalize $S S^\dagger$:

I first managed to diagonalize $C$ with a specific unitary matrix $U$:

$$UCU^\dagger = \begin{pmatrix} I &  \\ & 0  \end{pmatrix}\,,$$

where $I$ here is the identity matrix. In my previous comment I said that $C = \mathcal{U}^\dagger\,\mathcal{U}$, where $\mathcal{U}\,\mathcal{U}^\dagger = I$. $\mathcal{U}$ is a semi-unitary matrix of dimensions $m\times n$, therefore $C$ is a square matrix of dimensions $m\times m$ and the identity when diagonalizing $C$ is of dimensions $n\times n$ (I guess this should mean $n > m$, in my specific case $n = m + 3$).

And $s$, which is diagonal in the basis which I was working, has a different shape in a different basis:

$$U s U^T = s_{\mathrm{nd}} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & D \\ D^T & M \end{pmatrix}\,,$$

(if any of you are familiar with particle physics, this is the Seesaw matrix from which we get neutrino masses), where $M$ is a square symmetric matrix of dimension $m$. $D$ doesn't really have any special properties, but it is not a square matrix.

Now, $S S^\dagger$ has the shape:

$$S S^\dagger = sCs + C^T s^2 C^T\,,$$

this is due to all the properties that I wrote in the question. If we place a bunch of $U$'s in the middle of everything (I perhaps should've mentioned that $U$ is unitary):

$$
S S^\dagger = U^T U^\ast m U^\dagger U C U^\dagger U m U^T U^\ast + U^T U^\ast C^T U^T U^\ast m U^\dagger U m U^T U^\ast C^T U^T U^\ast
$$

$$
S S^\dagger = U^T \begin{pmatrix}D^\ast D^T & \\ & D^\dagger D  \end{pmatrix} U^\ast
$$

is block diagonal. The question was to obtain the eigenvalues, but this has left me satisfied enough for now. Diagonalizing $D^\dagger D$ is another different question, which I'll try on my own.

Thanks @Ben Grossmann for your comments.